# Seit wann bedeutet »irritierend« denn »verwirrend«?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Eigentlich müsste *irritierend* ja *störend* oder *reizend* (im negativen Sinn) bedeuten. Zumindest wäre das etymologisch konsequent. Wie und wann hat sich die Bedeutung dieses Wortes hin zu *verwirrend* gewandelt? Hat sich da irgend jemand gedacht, dass es vielleicht von *sich irren* kommen könnte? 
Ich finde das jedenfalls ziemlich ... irritierend.

Comment: Wenn man jemanden in seiner Konzentration oder Ordnung stört oder reizt, wird er doch verwirrt?

Comment: @tofro: Ja, aber er wird dann beispielsweise auch bei dem, was er tut, aufgehalten. Dennoch bedeutet *irritieren* nicht *aufhalten*.

Answer (score 8):

Du hast mit deiner Vermutung nicht ganz unrecht:

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/irritieren) sagt

> Das Wort taucht im 16. Jahrhundert in Deutschland auf und bedeutet reizen, erregen, provozieren. Es ist dem lateinischen irritare (aus Vorsilbe in- = ein- und ritare = aufregen) mit gleicher Wortbedeutung entlehnt. Im volkstümlichen Sprachgebrauch entstand durch die klangliche Nähe zu irr und irren im 19. Jhd. die Bedeutung ablenken, verunsichern, stören[1](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/irritieren)[2]

Es hat aber auch (zumindestens für mich) ein bißchen damit zu tun, dass ein "störender" oder "reizender" (mit Scheinangriffen und Scharmützeln) Feind in Caesars Schlachtenberichten immer *Störung* und *Durcheinander* in die Schlachtreihen brachte - Da liegt das "Verwirren" natürlich nicht weit.